# XML conditional parsing by javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, conditional-statements

I have the following xml file and I am trying to extract some elements

```
<entry>
    <form>
        <orth>Agathe</orth>
        <pron>agat</pron>
    </form>
    <gramGrp>
        <pos>n</pos>
    </gramGrp>
    <sense>
        <cit type="trans">
            <quote>Agatha</quote>
        </cit>
    </sense>
</entry>
<entry>
    <form>
        <orth>Aix-la-Chapelle</orth>
    </form>
    <gramGrp>
        <pos>n</pos>
    </gramGrp>
    <sense>
        <cit type="trans">
            <quote>Aix-la-Chapelle</quote>
        </cit>
    </sense>
</entry>
```

I already extracted all the elements  and  but I need only those that have n in the **pos** element.

```
function parseWordsAlt(xml) {

    // this reads the XML and puts the whole structure in the variable xmlDoc
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    // this takes all the entries which has tag names orth
    var resultOrth = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("orth");
    // this takes all the entries which has tag names orth
    var resultTranslation = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("quote");

    // cycles through the first n tags named orth
    var n=20;
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (var j=0;j<n;j++) {
            var resultWord1=resultOrth[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            var resultWord2=resultTranslation[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I am sorry for my bad jargon but I am new to this. 
Can you help me with this?

Comment: What browser(s) are you targeting?

Comment: I have the file on my computer, I just need to create another file with the results.

Comment: That does not answer the question, does it?

Comment: I wasn't sure. google chrome.

Comment: And you *have* to do it in the browser? If you want to get information out of XML files on your computer and you are not really interested in displaying them on a web page, then there are better ways of doing that than using a browser.

Comment: No I don't need to do it in the browser, but I only can write in javascript. How can I do it?

Comment: If you are on Linux you can use XML tools like [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) or [xmlsh](http://www.xmlsh.org/HomePage) to extract information from XML files. On Windows you can use the [Select-Xml cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) from PowerShell. In both cases you would use the [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query language.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few details that we don't know, as the environment that you are using, but here you have a small proof of concept that may help you to get a solution: check each entry and if it fulfill your condition, then take the values you need:

```js
var xml=document.getElementById("xml").innerHTML;

function parseWordsAlt(xmlDoc) {

    
    // this takes all the entries
    var entries = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
    for (var i=0;i<entries.length;i++) {
      var pos=entries[i].getElementsByTagName("pos");
      if (pos[0].textContent==="n") {
         var orth = entries[i].getElementsByTagName("orth")[0].textContent;
         var quote = entries[i].getElementsByTagName("quote")[0].textContent;
         console.log(`${orth},${quote}`);
      }
    }
}

parseWordsAlt(new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml"));
```

```html
<template id="xml">
<entries>
<entry>
    <form>
        <orth>Agathe</orth>
        <pron>agat</pron>
    </form>
    <gramGrp>
        <pos>n</pos>
    </gramGrp>
    <sense>
        <cit type="trans">
            <quote>Agatha</quote>
        </cit>
    </sense>
</entry>
<entry>
    <form>
        <orth>Aix-la-Chapelle</orth>
    </form>
    <gramGrp>
        <pos>n</pos>
    </gramGrp>
    <sense>
        <cit type="trans">
            <quote>Aix-la-Chapelle</quote>
        </cit>
    </sense>
</entry>
</entries>
</template>
```